# Maintain data integrity in circular references in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints, data-integrity

Lets say we have three tables Customer, City and Country

The Country table:

- ID(PK)
- Name.

The City table:

- ID (PK)
- CountryID (FK)
- Name

The Customer table:

- ID(PK)
- CountryID(FK)(NULL)
- CityID(FK)(NULL)
- Name
  etc ...

As you can guess the Customer may or may not have assigned CityID or CountryID.

So what is the best way to ensure that when inserting/updating a Customer we do not end up with a City that is not in the specified Country?

Comment: as far as Country is only needed id city is not know, clear CountryID on assigning CityID. Query would be IsNull(CountryFromCityLookUp,CountryLookup) as Country.

Comment: And what is the appropriate syntax for a CHECK constraing or a TRIGGER? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that would be the best way but you could add a function and use it in your check constraint:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckCityInCountry(@CityID int, @CountryID int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) 
     FROM Cityies CI inner join Countries CO on (CI.CountryID, CO.ID)
     WHERE CO.CountryID = @CountryID and CityID = @CityID
   RETURN @retval
END;
GO
```

This function will return 1 if the city is in a country and 0 otherwise.

Then add a check constraint using that function:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_CheckCityInCountry CHECK (
   CityID is null OR
   dbo.CheckCityInCountry(CityID,CountryID) >= 1
);
GO
```

Comment: This is a good idea :) however you've missed the CountryID parameter of CheckCityInCountry. We are not trying to determine if a city exists at all what we want here is to check if the Customer has assigned country and later on somebody assigns a City to that Customer to make sure that the City's CountryID matches the CountryID of the customer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I would be very, very, very careful about using UDFs in check constraints. See http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/301828 (closed as won't fix), https://sqlblog.org/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Are you aware of a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Set up the FK relationships to BOTH the Country and City tables

Change the City table to have composite PK of CountryID, CityID.
That FK relationship must reference both.

The FK is not enforced on null.

One caveat is you can enter bad CityID with a null country as at that point neither FK is enforced.
But I think that could be enforced with a CHECK CONSTRAINT.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerCountyCity ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CustomerCountyCity
    CHECK (CountryID is not null OR CityID is Null)
```